# Load external JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I can't seem to get JSON when it's from an external file. When I write it inline, it works fine. But when I created a file called `test.json` and copied the JSON in to it, I never get the contents.

Here's my HTML and JavaScript. I should note that both HTML and JSON files are within the same folder.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON Sandbox</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>JSON Sandbox</h2>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var text = $.getJSON({
                dataType : "json",
                url : "test.json",
                data : data,
                success : window.alert("JSON Aquired.")

            });

            var obj = JSON.parse(text);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name + "<br>" + obj.street + "<br>" + obj.phone;
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my `test.json` file

```
{
    "name":"John Johnson",
    "street":"Oslo West 1",
    "phone":"111 1234567"
}
```

Comment: Try and check : Create a `*.js` file inspite of `*.json`..

Comment: Don't edit the answer into your question, please.

Comment: That didn't do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the file extension to js.
and change the html file as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON Sandbox</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>JSON Sandbox</h2>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var obj = new Object();
            var error = new Object();
            $.getJSON('test.js').done(function (data) {
                obj = data;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name + "<br>" + obj.street + "<br>" + obj.phone;
            }).error(function (err) {
                error = err;
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still not working, you can check it out at http://dev.tessierit.com/json/index.html

Comment: try downloading the googleapis js file to local folder and then referencing it as  <script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: There is absolutely no reason anything suggested in this answer after the code should have made a difference. I'm not sure what happened, but kudos, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your success handler is defined incorrectly.

Replace:

```
success : window.alert("JSON Aquired.")
```

With:

```
success : function(data){
    window.alert("JSON Aquired.")
    // `data` is the returned object:
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.name + "<br>" + data.street + "<br>" + data.phone;
}
```

You need to do what you want to do with the data, in the `success` handler, because `$.getJSON` is an AJAX call, which means it's asynchronous.

Comment: You'll also have to move the code that uses the data into the success handler.

Comment: @RyanKinal: just noticed that, adding it to my answer.

Comment: @Frantumn: Are you getting any errors? What do you see when you `console.log(data)` in the success handler?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
this is on the var text line.

Comment: Make sure you've included jQuery properly.

Comment: Why do I need Jquery? When I use the exact code on this example, it doesn't include jquery, and it worked for me. http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: `$.getJSON` is a jQuery function. The example you're linking to is just a static object.

Comment: Okay, I've included it and the error goes away, but there's still nothing showing up.

Comment: _"What do you see when you `console.log(data)` in the success handler?"_